# Does Keep score points when another Keep is completed?

Tags: carcassonne

In Carcassonne Bridges, Castles, and Bazaars expansion you may build a keep on a completed 2-tile city and it will score points once other features are completed in its vicinity. What if the other feature is also a keep? Does it score as a 2-point city, or does it not count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a Keep is built next to another Keep, neither are completed as a city. The next feature that's scored next to *either* of them, though, will trigger both. First the Keep that's next to the feature, and then the other Keep that's adjacent to the now-finished Keep.